# Access report has to be refreshed to show data

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-reports

I have a button that when pressed, opens a report on the record selected in that form. Here is the code for the button:

```
blnSave = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit this student?", vbYesNo, "Exit Confirmation")
If blnSave = True Then
            DoCmd.OpenReport "rptExitNotice", acViewPreview, , "[BehaviourID]=" & Me.BehaviourID
            DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmExitStudent"
            End If
```

When the form closes and the report opens, all the fields in the report are blank:
[image: Empty Report]
When you press F5, the data appear perfectly in place:
[image: Complete Report]

I have tried putting both Me.Refresh, DoCmd.Requery and DoCmd.Refresh in the Open, No Data and Activate events, but they give these errors:
[image: Method or data member not found]
[image: The command or action "Refresh Record" isn't available now]

How can I get the report to show the data first time round?
Is there a problem with the button's code?
Or should I add a Me.Refresh or something similar in a different event?

Comment: Perhaps `Me.Requery` ?

Answer (score 0):

I scrapped the code in the On Load, On Open, etc. and created a form with a timer of 1000 and the timer event executes this code:

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
Dim rpt As Report

With Reports
    ' Iterate over all open reports...
    For Each rpt In Reports
        rpt.Requery
    Next
End With
lblStatus.Caption = "Generation Complete"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmRefreshReport"
End Sub
```

The form refreshes the report and then closes. There is a little status label that changes text when the refresh is complete (to make it look nicer for end users). The form opens when the report opens, so the report gets refreshed by the form that then closes itself, saving the user pressisng F5.
Source: [How to automatically reload a report in MS Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264598/how-to-automatically-reload-a-report-in-ms-access)